# Using Returned Value in Later Function

Tags: python, function, return-value

Let's say I wanted to call a function to do some calculation, but I also wanted to use that calculated value in a later function. When I return the value of the first function can I not just send it to my next function? Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
def add(x,y):
  addition = x + y
  return addition

def square(a):
  result = a * a
  return result

sum = add(1,4)
product = square(addition)
```

If I call the add function, it'll return 5 as the addition result. But I want to use that number 5 in the next function, can I just send it to the next function as shown? In the main program I am working on it does not work like this.

Edit: This is a sample of the code I am actually working on which will give a better idea of what the problem is. The problem is when I send the mean to the calculateStdDev function.

```
#import libraries to be used
import time
import StatisticsCalculations

#global variables
mean = 0
stdDev = 0

#get file from user
fileChoice = input("Enter the .csv file name: ") 
inputFile = open(fileChoice)

headers = inputFile.readline().strip('ï»¿\n').split(',') #create headers for columns and strips unnecessary characters

#create a list with header-number of lists in it
dataColumns = []
for i in headers:
  dataColumns.append([]) #fills inital list with as many empty lists as there are columns

#counts how many rows there are and adds a column of data into each empty list
rowCount = 0
for row in inputFile:
  rowCount = rowCount + 1
  comps = row.strip().split(',') #components of data
  for j in range(len(comps)):
    dataColumns[j].append(float(comps[j])) #appends the jth entry into the jth column, separating data into categories

k = 0
for entry in dataColumns:
  print("{:>11}".format(headers[k]),"|", "{:>10.2f}".format(StatisticsCalculations.findMax(dataColumns[k])),"|", 
    "{:>10.2f}".format(StatisticsCalculations.findMin(dataColumns[k])),"|","{:>10.2f}".format(StatisticsCalculations.calculateMean(dataColumns[k], rowCount)),"|","{:>10.2f}".format()) #format each data entry to be right aligned and be correctly spaced in its column
#prining break line for each row
  k = k + 1 #counting until dataColumns is exhausted

inputFile.close()
```

And the StatisticsCalculations module:

```
import math

def calculateMean(data, rowCount):
  sumForMean = 0
  for entry in data:
    sumForMean = sumForMean + entry
    mean = sumForMean/rowCount

  return mean

def calculateStdDev(data, mean, rowCount, entry):
  stdDevSum = 0 
  for x in data: 
    stdDevSum = float(stdDevSum) + ((float(entry[x]) - mean)** 2) #getting sum of squared difference to be used in std dev formula
  stdDev = math.sqrt(stdDevSum / rowCount) #using the stdDevSum for the remaining parts of std dev formula

  return stdDev


def findMin(data):
  lowestNum = 1000
  for component in data:
    if component < lowestNum:
      lowestNum = component

  return lowestNum

def findMax(data):
  highestNum = -1
  for number in data:
    if number > highestNum:
      highestNum = number

  return highestNum
```

Comment: Take a look at global variables

Comment: Not sure I understand - why not just do `product = square(sum)` ?

Comment: Do `product = square(add(1,4))`

Comment: Man! If you take a look your returned `addition` is your `sum = add(1,4)`, I mean your `sum` variable, so just do: `product = square(sum)`, may help you!

Comment: @Tuna I now realize this example may not have been the best as it is quite simple! I would show my actual code, but it is quite a lot to paste in here!

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci global variables are very rarely the correct solution

Comment: Oh, sorry! Tell me, Is your variable a local or a global variable?

Comment: @Tuna check the updated post for my a section of my actual program

Comment: Is this case why pass mean as an argument?  In your case perhaps it would be better to call `calculateMean` from within `calculateStdDev` .

Comment: @DarrylG Forgive me if I am ignorant, but wouldn't this make the program less systematic? I want to achieve a somewhat simplistic flow to the program.

Comment: @ThatOneNerdyBoy--actually, it makes it more the typical.  For example, Python library function [statistics.stdev](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.stdev) only inputs the data so it must calculate the mean internally as it computes the standard deviation.

Comment: First, forget those global variables `(mean = 0; stdDev=0)`, delete them! Second, when you import your `StatisticsCalculations` module you should call first your method `calculateMean`, because it returns your real `mean`, i.e.,  `mean = sumForMean/rowCount` (but remember, you can only access your `mean` through `calculateMean`, so save that value in a variable e.g. `mean_ex = calculateMean([...])`), so after that you can run your `calculateStdDev` method just doing `calculateStdDev(data, mean_ex, [...])`

Comment: Oh, if you don't want call your `calculateMean()` method in your main class you can take another approach inside your `StatisticsCalculations` module, i.e. run your `calculateMean()` inside your `calculateStdDev()`, that's is a great approach actually! For that you just need make the due alterations in your `calculateStdDev()`! If you wish I can show you a quick example! May help you!

Comment: That worked, thanks @Tuna!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `sum` is a reserved word, you shouldn't use it as a variable.

You can do it this way:

```py
def add(x,y):
  addition = x + y
  return addition

def square(a):
  result = a * a
  return result

s = add(1, 4)
product = square(s)
```

Or directly:

```py
product = square(add(1, 4))
```